# Magento 2 How to remove labels from checkout page fields and add placeholder instead?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Currently, I'm using the extension for one step checkout and I want to remove labels from all the fields and want to use placeholder instead of those labels.

So how can I find the knockout template which is rendering those fields and how can I change it to remove labels and add placeholder there.

Please help me for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your one step checkout extensions name ??

Comment: @MohitPatel I am using aheadworks one step checkout.